How can I use a vue component in a named slot which is created outside of the template?
I have a Vue SFC Playground
My display and display-two component need access to a data provided by provider. The computation of this data is expensive and provider should only exist if needed.
display-three has no need for the data provided by provider.
For various reasons, in the real case, it is impractical to place provider and display-three inside of displayer.
When either display, display-two, or display-three are to be displayed, I would like to send the created component to the named slot todisplay inside of displayer. I am not sure how to do that or if it is possible.
Here is the code for reference:
App.vue
<template>
  <button @click="rotate">Rotate</button>
  
  <displayer>
    <template #todisplay>
      <!-- either display, display-two, or display-three displayed ONLY here -->
    </template>
  </displayer>  

  <provider v-if="providerDisplay">
    <display v-if="which === 0" />
    <display-two v-if="which === 1" />
  </provider>

  <display-three v-if="which === 2" />
  
</template>


<script setup>
import { ref, computed } from 'vue'

const which = ref(0)

import Provider from './Provider.vue'
import Display from './Display.vue'
import DisplayTwo from './DisplayTwo.vue'
import DisplayThree from './DisplayThree.vue'
import Displayer from './Displayer.vue'

const providerDisplay = computed(() => which.value === 0 || which.value === 1)

function rotate() {
  which.value = ( which.value + 1 ) % 3
}

</script>

Provider.vue
<template>
  <slot />
</template>


<script setup>
import { provide, ref } from 'vue'

const variable = ref("hello, world!")

provide( 'variable', variable )
</script>

Display.vue
<template>
  <div>
    Display {{ variable }}
  </div>
</template>


<script setup>
import { inject } from 'vue'

const variable = inject('variable')

</script>

DisplayTwo.vue
<template>
  <div>
    Display Two {{ variable }}
  </div>
</template>


<script setup>
import { inject } from 'vue'

const variable = inject('variable')

</script>

DisplayThree.vue
<template>
  <div>
    Display Three
  </div>
</template>


<script setup></script>

Displayer.vue
<template>
  <div style="background-color: red;">
    <slot name="todisplay"/>
  </div>
</template>


<script setup>
</script>

I have an alternative if this turns out to not be possible. I am curious to find out if it is. If it is, how?

Dynamic Components
  <displayer>
    <template #todisplay>
      <!-- either display, display-two, or display-three displayed ONLY here -->
      <component :is="current"></component>
    </template>
  </displayer>  

...


let current = ref(Display);

const comps = {
  0: Display,
  1: DisplayTwo,
  2: DisplayThree
}

function rotate() {
  which.value = ( which.value + 1 ) % 3
  current.value = comps[which.value]
}

